# Different definitions for integration on $L^{2}$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

If $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\cap L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, the integral:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} f(x) dx$$
is a well-defined object. If, however, $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, we can define a different notion of the above integral by setting:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}f(x)dx := \lim_{M \to \infty}\int_{|x| \le M}f(x)dx$$
provided the limit exists.

I have two questions concerning the above integral.

**Q1:** Is the second integral equivalent to the first one when restricted to $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\cap L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, i.e. when $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\cap L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$?

**Q2:** Suppose $K$ is an integral operator on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\cap L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, so that:
$$(Kf)(x) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}K(x,y)f(y)dy$$
where I'm using the usual (first) integral. If $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ are both integral operators with integral kernels $K_{1}(x,y)$ and $K_{2}(x,y)$, then the operator $K := K_{1}K_{2}$ has integral kernel:
$$K(x,y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} K_{1}(x,z)K_{2}(z,y)dz$$
Does the same property hold when $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\cap L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is replaced by $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and the second notion of integral is used?

Comment: A detail. When you say that the limit over M is taken w.r.t. L2 norm what do you mean? The limit over M is over the real numbers with the usual topology no?

Comment: The equivalence of both definitions for $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)\cap L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ shold follow using dominated convergence theorem. However, for $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)\setminus L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ the second notion of integral does not seem to be very well behaved.

Comment: @Thomas ops! Fixed.

Comment: What are your assumptions on $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$?  How do you deduce that $K$ has the given form?  Is the integral kernel for $K$ finite?  Before we go to $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, we should firm up the $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \cap L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ case.